# Northwind Starters Kit

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, adventureworks

Is the Northwind Starter Kit from Codeplex a good starting point to learn more about how to best architect an ASP.NET application?

Is there something similar for the AdventureWorks database examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Northwind database was the best sample database for SQL Server 2000.

Talk about SQL Server 2005, AdventureWorks is better than Northwind. Northwind is not the best database due to few new features of analysis and reporting service of SQL Server 2005.

MSDN Book On Line (BOL) uses the AdventureWorks in all of their example and it makes it easy to follow up if proper understanding of AdventureWorks schema is developed.

However, SQL Server Compact Edition uses Northwind as sample database. So decide on basis of your version.

Answer (score 1):

AdventureWorks database is the one that I prefer since it has a lot of advanced scenarios and is used in the samples for SQL Server Analysis Service. Analysis service is MS Business Intelligence Platform and it need to have a good amount of data for explaining the scenarios.

Comment: AdventureWorks is more advanced, true, but in my experience in the "real world" most companies databases seem to be more like Northwind than AdventureWorks; I've never seen a real-world database as heavily normalized as AdventureWorks.

Answer (score 1):

The NSF is not just a database sample, it has layered (domain-driven) .net examples to help developers understand a real-world implementation of various design principles (OOD, SOLID) and how those design principles are often applied via design patterns across multiple layers. So, check out NSF for more than just the Northwind database.